# infinitive clause and subject

Tags: infinitives, subjects

> 1.He invented a business plan which companies can employ (to earn profits.)

I bracketed the part which I think is the purpose adjunct,
the understood subject of the infinitive is **companies**, right?

can the relative clause be viewed as:
Companies can employ the business plan to earn profits?

> 2.He is asked to investigate [what the police believe to be the root of the crime] (to discover the truth.)

The first infinitive **to be the root of the crime**,
the understood subject is relative pronoun **what**,right?
Can the noun phrase be viewed as:
The police believe what to be the root of the crime?

The second infinitive **to discover the truth** is a purpose adjunct,
and the understood subject is **he**?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake: It can be: ***He is asked to interrogate [some person].*** OR ***He is asked to interrogate [some person] to discover the truth.***  I see now that the bits in parenthesis and brackets were explanatory.

Comment: to use or make use of a business plan, not employ it.

Answer (score 0):

> *He invented a business plan* [*which companies can employ (to earn profits)*
>   *profits*].

Your analyses are essentially correct.

> *He is asked to interrogate* [*who the police believe to be the suspect*
>   *(to discover the truth.)*]

Unfortunately, this sentence is ungrammatical. The element in square brackets is a 'fused' relative construction, a noun phrase. But in today's Standard English fused "who" is more or less restricted to the particular use called the 'free choice' construction, as in *You can bring* [*who(ever) you like*].

Comment: Thanks, I am so happy to find out my first analyses are correct! I changed the ungrammatical sentence and used **what** to lead the noun phrase, and modified my analyses accordingly. Are the sentence and analyses both correct now?

Comment: Okay, but the system doesn't permit me to delete it, i will post a new one again.

Comment: This is a _wh_-cleft construction, and one of its restrictions is that, whereas _what_ and many other _wh_-words can occur in it, _who_ can't. _What you want is not here/*Who you're looking for is not here._